# How to return my label to it's initial position (UIGestureRecognizer) in Swift

Tags: swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am moving a label around the screen and I want it to go back to it's initial position after I remove my finger off it, for now it's stays there! Any help would be appreciated.

```
@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) { 
    let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)

    if let view = recognizer.view {
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)
    }
    recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)

    if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
        //What code to add to return my Label to it's initial position??
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Save in a variable your initial center position `view.center` at start dragging, and when you end up moving your `UIView` around set this value again.

Try this out:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var initial : CGPoint?

@IBAction func handlePan(recognizer:UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view {
        if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Began {
           initial = view.center
        }
        else if recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended {
           view.center = initial!
           return
        }

        let translation = recognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        view.center = CGPoint(x:view.center.x + translation.x, y:view.center.y + translation.y)
        recognizer.setTranslation(CGPointZero, inView: self.view)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works fine! At the same time I have another question. Let say I want to move this label inside another empty label or empty box, can I use an empty UILabel? How can I detect that my label is 'over' my empty label?

Comment: @TommyBrisson ...that matter should be in another question as is not directly related to this one. you will obtain better results that way, I could answer but need more research to provide a good one. Please, search if there is no other question like that one in stackoverflow and if not, feel free to ask. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe inside the function `touchesEnded` you can reset the label's position.

Hope that helps :)